# Как в Swift отсортировать данные Core Data по русскому алфавиту А-Я? Как убрать 'Ё' из начала списка? NSFetchRequest, NSSortDecriptor, Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, coredata

Моя текущая сортировка сначала выдает слова на букву 'Ё', а только потом идет А-Я.

В столбце name лежат русские слова.

```
func searching(_ text: String?) {
    let searchFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Word")
    searchFetch.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", text!)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    searchFetch.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        words = try managedObjectContext.fetch(searchFetch) as! [Word]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch words: \(error)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Как написать правильный comparator для NSSortDescriptor? Или есть другие идеи?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение простое: При сортировке необходимо указать локализацию для NSSortDescriptor с помощью #selector:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
```

Таким образом, NSSortDescriptor понимает, что мы из России, и что мы хотим алфавит в правильном порядке А-Я без всяких "Ё" в начале

Answer (score 0):

http://foxtools.ru/Unicode Буква 'Ё' стоит раньше чем остальные буквы алфавита. Отталкивайтесь от этого